# Solr 8.4 date issue

Tags: solr, upgrade

We are migrating Sitecore 8.2 to 10.1 and also Solr 6.6.2 to Solr 8.4.

The indexes in Solr 8.4 are building fine. But, there is issue with the date.

The search result looks like this

[image: search result]

The publication date should be 05 November 2019 but it is coming as 05. This publication date issue is across all the search.

There is not much help in the logs. Is there any date issue in Solr 8.4?

Updated*

After doing some more investigation, the date format is not working.

This is the date format dd MMMM yyyy. Only **dd** is working from the date format. How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Isn't it just a date format displayed in frontend? That you display day only?

Comment: Could you please share what output is coming in Solr panel for particular this field?